Cant change height/width of button in tkinter grid button
I have multiple buttons all being created via ttk.Button() where it asks for the Tk variable name, text, and command. I add them to the grid via varname.grid where it puts it in a row, column, padding, and for input for sticky. my problem is adding the height= or width= in both of them.
i tried adding height= and width= in both ttk.Button and varname.grid with them both returning errors. I've attached the tkinter part of my code without my commands to make it more simple for others, however I can add the functions in if it would make it easier for others. Thanks for the help
# Main GUI window
window = Tk()
window.title("Media Player")

# Create buttons
select_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Select File", command=select_file)
play_pause_button = ttk.Button(window,text="Play", command=play_music)
stop_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=stop_music)
rewind_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Rewind", command=lambda: rewind_music())
fast_forward_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Fast Forward", command=lambda: fast_forward_music())
skip_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Skip Song", command=lambda: play_next())
previous_song_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Previous Song", command=lambda: play_previous())

# Create playlist controls
playlist_label = ttk.Label(window, text="Playlist")
playlist_box = Listbox(window, selectbackground="#3498db", selectforeground="white")
remove_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Remove", command=remove_from_playlist)
shuffle_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Shuffle", command=shuffle_playlist)
clear_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Clear", command=clear_playlist)

# Create volume control
volume_label = ttk.Label(window, text="Volume")
volume_scale = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0.0, to=1.0, orient="horizontal", command=set_volume)
volume_scale.set(volume)  # Set initial volume value

# Create status label
status_label = ttk.Label(window, text="", anchor="center")

# Position the buttons and widgets
select_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
play_pause_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
stop_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
rewind_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
fast_forward_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
skip_button.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)
previous_song_button.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=10, pady=10)
playlist_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
playlist_box.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=4, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
remove_button.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="w")
shuffle_button.grid(row=2, column=6, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="w")
clear_button.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="w")
volume_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
volume_scale.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="we")
status_label.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=6, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="we")

# Configure grid weights
window.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()


Configuration of height is not supported in ttk.Button per Changing ttk Button Height in Python
However width is supported by ttk.Button.
I don't see where you are trying to add width in your example code, so I've taken two of the buttons (remove_button, and shuffle_button) and placed a width of 100 on remove_button.
<-SNIP->
remove_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Remove", width=100, command=remove_from_playlist)
shuffle_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Shuffle", command=shuffle_playlist)

<-SNIP->
In the future, you can see what config keys are supported for a tk widget with:
print(remove_button.config().keys())
# Supported config keys:
# dict_keys(['command', 'default', 'takefocus', 'text', 'textvariable', 'underline', 'width', 'image', 'compound', 'padding', 'state', 'cursor', 'style', 
'class'])

Additionally, for ttk widgets you can check what ttk.Style keys are supported for a specific ttk widget with:
print(ttk.Style().configure(remove_button.winfo_class()).keys())
# Supported Style config keys:
# dict_keys(['padding', 'anchor', 'width'])

where remove_button is the name of the widget you are querying.  In this case, I am querying the remove_button key.
Image showing example code result

there are 2 options that you could do. ttk only has options to adjust the width for a button. if you change from ttk.Button to just Button you can set the height and width of your buttons on creation. however if you want to use ttk down in your grid instead of using padx=5, pady=10 you can use ipadx=10, ipady=30. that will set the internal padding of your buttons and can stretch and grow them as you need. but it will adjust the layout of the rest of your window and affect other items in the same columns/rows if they need to be diffent sizes
